# Grouping by time ignoring the Date portion

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a column that is called scores and another one that is called date_time

I am trying to find out for each 5 minute time increment how many I have that are above a certain score. I want to ignore the date portion completely and just base this off of time.

This is kind of like in a stats program where they display your peak hours with the only difference that I want to go is detailed as 5 minute time segments.

I am still fairly new at MySQL and Google seems to be my best companion.

What I have found so far is:

```
SELECT id, score, date_time, COUNT(id)
FROM data
WHERE score >= 500
GROUP BY TIME(date_time) DIV 300;
```

Would this work or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: it supposedly does the 5 min increment (5 min * 60 second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your query would work.  You need to do a bit more work to get the time rounded to 5 minute intervals.  Something like:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(time(date_time))/300)*300) as time5, COUNT(id)
FROM data
WHERE score >= 500
GROUP BY SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(time(date_time))/300)*300)
ORDER BY time5;
```

Comment: I got it to work, somehow sqlyog was messing things up. Thanks for the query.